# Can't cast video via google cast correctly in ios app

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast, google-cast

I'm working on a project with custom video player, based on AVPlayer. Trying to integrate google cast. I've made integration based on google tuts: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-ios/
But with conversion to swift. Everything seems to work fine, when cast, if video player opens, and there is connected device (or if I connect from panel), I form meta info for file, and it's passed to google cast - everything works fine.

But, i have strange behavior:
1) Start casting, open video, then another video, then third video.
2) Stop casting
3) Go to another video, enable casting, but it doesn't start this video. It start casting the first video I opened earlier....

I tried to find any method that clears cache or queue, but there is no.. Please, help

```
class VideoVC: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, GCKSessionManagerListener {

var filmTitle: String!
var toPass: String!
var film: MovieDetails!
var filmDetails: Movie!
var sessionManager: GCKSessionManager?
var castSession: GCKCastSession?
var castMediaController: GCKUIMediaController?
var checkPlayed = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sessionManager = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager

    sessionManager?.add(self)

    castMediaController = GCKUIMediaController()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    if let videoURL = toPass {

        if let video = URL(string: videoURL) {
            player = AVPlayer(url: video)

            player.allowsExternalPlayback = true
            player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true

            playerController.player = player
            self.addChildViewController(playerController)
            self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
            playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.sendSubview(toBack: playerController.view)
        }
    }

    if isCastEnabled() {
        playSelectedItemRemotely()
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)

}

func buildMediaInformation() -> GCKMediaInformation {
    let metaData = GCKMediaMetadata(metadataType: GCKMediaMetadataType(rawValue: 1)!)

    metaData.setString(filmTitle, forKey: kGCKMetadataKeyTitle)

    if let imageUrl = URL(string: filmDetails.poster_cast!) {
        let image = GCKImage(url: imageUrl, width: 340, height: 450)
        metaData.addImage(image)
    }

    if let episode = film.serial_episode, let season = film.serial_season, season != "", episode != "", let title = film.title, title != "" {
        let subtitle = "\(title) \(episode) серия \(season) сезон"
        metaData.setString(subtitle, forKey: kGCKMetadataKeySubtitle)
    }


    let duration = Double(film.duration!)

    let mediaInfo = GCKMediaInformation(contentID: toPass!,
                                        streamType: GCKMediaStreamType.buffered,
                                        contentType: film.contentType!,
                                        metadata: metaData as GCKMediaMetadata,
                                        streamDuration: duration,
                                        mediaTracks: nil,
                                        textTrackStyle: nil,
                                        customData: nil)

    print("toPass: \(toPass!)")
    print("duration: \(duration)")

    return mediaInfo
}

func playSelectedItemRemotely() {

    let castSession = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
    if (castSession != nil) {
        castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(self.buildMediaInformation(), autoplay: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("no castSession!")
    }
}

func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStart session: GCKSession) {
    playSelectedItemRemotely()
}

func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didResumeSession session: GCKSession) {

}

func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didEnd session: GCKSession, withError error: Error?) {
    let castSession = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
    castSession?.endAndStopCasting(true)
}

func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didFailToStart session: GCKSession, withError error: Error) {
    Utils.showOverAnyVC("Ошибка подключения", message: "Попробуйте еще раз!")
}

func isCastEnabled() -> Bool {
    switch GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().castState {
    case GCKCastState.connected:
        print("cast connected")
        return true
    case GCKCastState.connecting:
        print("cast connecting")
        return true
    case GCKCastState.notConnected:
        print("cast notConnected")
        return false
    case GCKCastState.noDevicesAvailable:
        print("cast noDevicesAvailable")
        return false
    }
}}
```

and my appdelegate:

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GCKLoggerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let options = GCKCastOptions(receiverApplicationID: "F443E49F")
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)

    GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    let appStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewMain", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController = appStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigation")
    let castContainerVC: GCKUICastContainerViewController = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().createCastContainerController(for: navigationController)
    castContainerVC.miniMediaControlsItemEnabled = true
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = castContainerVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = true

    return true
}



func logMessage(_ message: String, fromFunction function: String) {
    print("message: \(function)")
}}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code sample to only the part that is experiencing a problem. Currently it is hard to find the problematic part

Comment: Sure, reduced code only for google cast methods, and add delegate with cast methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possible solution could be due to:

```
sessionManager?.add(self)
```

You add the delegate but at no point do you clear it. As a result, the `VideoVC` is never destroyed due to the retained reference from the session manager. When you reopen the `VideoVC` the session manager is still also accessing the delegate from the first time you loaded it.

Because of this, when the following is called:

```
func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStart session: GCKSession) {
```

This is being called in your first instance of `VideoVC` which now has the wrong file information.

You can monitor this by putting a print(self) into the above method and look at the memory pointer value. Check that it also matches the same memory pointer value that is called in `viewDidLoad`

**Update**

To better manage the delegate change the following method: `viewDidDisappear()`

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)

    //this stops the session manager sending callbacks to your VideoVC
    sessionManager.remove(self)
}
```

Comment: yes, Matthew, you are right, delegate prints first memory pointer, which is not the same as in viewdidload. How can I reset or delete self after dismiss or when cast is disabled?

Comment: also, I tested, it's better to remove delegate in session didEnd method 

didEnd session

in viewDidDisappear, this also removes widget with controls

Comment: @Matthew, please help. I don't want to play video using iOS cast SDK. I just need to mirror(show) my app screen(view controller content) to TV(large display). What API I can use? any reference? I am struggling!

Comment: @JamshedAlam - I'm not entirely sure what would be the best option for this. There are applications you can download that will allow this too work and an SDK provided by letsview.com however I'm not sure on their pricing.

Outside of that, the best I could find, open source, is this sample project called CastRemoteDisplay, however it is a few years old so I'm not sure how well it would work. It may at least give you a starting point: https://github.com/jrgrafton/CastRemoteDisplay-iOS

Comment: thanks for your reply. I contacted letsview, still no reply. Also got the GitHub example you gave earlier, almost impossible to manage the source code because all SDKs change a lot. Some classes got deprecate. i am trying with this. One thing to share with you, I browsed most of the APIs in iOS cast SDK documentation, everywhere they talk to play media, no screen mirroring example is there. Is it really possible with iOS cast SDK ? or they removed the support? maybe just allowing it manually from browser/their app. i am not sure!

Comment: @JamshedAlam - Honestly I'm not entirely sure. There maybe something you can do with the PRScreenRecorder (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder?changes=latest_minor) and redirect the buffer stream into the input for iOS Cast. It may create a delay between the device and what you see on screen but could be possible. Note that this idea it purely theorectical and I don't know if it would actually work, but technically, it seems feasible.