# Google ChromeCast iOS (Swift 3) can't play video

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I need help! Once i connected the device to chromecast, it crashed right when it's about to load. I have no clue why it cause that. I followed GoogleCast for Docs and few examples and seems that it's missing something. Could you guys help me?

This my code

This is on my OnCreate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        sessionManager = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager
        sessionManager?.add(self)
        castMediaController = GCKUIMediaController()

        if isCastEnabled() {
            playSelectedItemRemotely()
        }
}

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                  //
    //            Start du Google ChromeCast            //
    //                                                  //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    private func buildMediaInformation() -> GCKMediaInformation {

        let metadata = GCKMediaMetadata(metadataType: GCKMediaMetadataType.generic)
        metadata.setString("Title", forKey: kGCKMetadataKeyTitle)
        metadata.setString("Studio", forKey: kGCKMetadataKeyStudio)

        let mediaInfo = GCKMediaInformation(contentID: "streamURL",
                                                 streamType: GCKMediaStreamType.none,
                                                 contentType: "video/m3u",
                                                 metadata: metadata,
                                                 streamDuration: 60,
                                                 mediaTracks: nil,
                                                 textTrackStyle: nil,
                                                 customData: nil)
        print(mediaInfo.contentID)
        return mediaInfo
    }


    func isCastEnabled() -> Bool {
        switch GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().castState {
        case GCKCastState.connected:
            print("cast connected")
            return true
        case GCKCastState.connecting:
            print("cast connecting")
            return true
        case GCKCastState.notConnected:
            print("cast notConnected")
            return false
        case GCKCastState.noDevicesAvailable:
            print("cast noDevicesAvailable")
            return false
        }
    }

    func playSelectedItemRemotely() {

        let castSession = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
        if (castSession != nil) {
            castSession?.remoteMediaClient?.loadMedia(self.buildMediaInformation(), autoplay: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("no castSession!")
        }
    }




    func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStart session: GCKSession) {
        playSelectedItemRemotely()
    }

    func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didResumeSession session: GCKSession) {

    }

    func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didEnd session: GCKSession, withError error: Error?) {
        let castSession = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession
        castSession?.endAndStopCasting(true)
    }

    func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didFailToStart session: GCKSession, withError error: Error) {

    }


    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

//        playerView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
//        
//        //this stops the session manager sending callbacks to your VideoVC
//        sessionManager?.remove(self)



    }
```

And this is on my AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let castAppID = "myKey"
        let options = GCKCastOptions.init(receiverApplicationID: castAppID)
        GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
        GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/42603550/5995040

Comment: its not duplicate at all and far from this other question

Answer (score 1):

I got it. My issue was in the Google Cast Console i had a remote receiver. Need to have a custom style receiver or media. So make sure you have that right!! Or just use a kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID on your AppID to get the default one.